# Как переписать данный запрос на PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Есть вот такой запрос

```
    $sqlCrt = "SELECT n.*,u.name AS author, p.name AS person, s.name AS work, cf.name AS client_firm_name, CONCAT(cp.lastname,' ',cp.name) AS client_person_name, mp.name AS media_project
  FROM $dbtable[work_task] n
  LEFT JOIN $dbtable[user] u ON u.id=n.id_author
  LEFT JOIN $dbtable[user] p ON p.id=n.id_person
  LEFT JOIN $dbtable[work] s ON n.id_work=s.id
  LEFT JOIN $dbtable[work_firm] cf ON n.client_firm=cf.id
  LEFT JOIN $dbtable[work_author] cp ON n.client_person=cp.id
  LEFT JOIN $dbtable[media_project] mp ON n.id_project=mp.id
  WHERE n.status<3 AND (n.fdate>='$startOfWeek' AND n.fdate<'$next') AND n.id_person='$user_id'";

$resultCrt = dbq($sqlCrt);
for ($i = 0; $i < @mysql_numrows($result); $i++) {
    //якорь массив
    $ar = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Как можно данный отрезок кода переписать с использованием технологии PDO? Конкретно, я не понимаю, как преобразовать эти многочисленные `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: pdo - это не про запросы, а про интерфейс доступа к базе. Тот же запрос будет работать замечательно. *Только цикл на while поменять*

Comment: И прямую вставку в запрос из переменных на плейсхолдеры. И всё неплохо будет

Comment: @vp_arth я имею ввиду, что нужно поменять в плане синтаксиса, чтобы он работал через интерфейс pdo?)

Comment: Вместо `WHERE n.status<3 AND (n.fdate>='$startOfWeek' AND n.fdate<'$next') AND n.id_person='$user_id'` писать, например, так `WHERE n.status<3 AND (n.fdate>=:startOfWeek AND n.fdate<:next) AND n.id_person=:user_id'`

Comment: @ArchDemon а для чего менять `for` на `while`, подскажите, пожалуйста)

Comment: В sql-запросе можно ничего не менять. Пока. А «как выполнить sql-запрос с помощью pdo», это другой и, вероятно, более полезный вопрос. Можете задать его отдельно тут же.

Comment: Потому что так короче.

Answer (score 2):

**PDO** - это не про запросы, а про интерфейс доступа к базе.
Тот же запрос будет работать замечательно.

#### SQL-запрос

> <strike>$result = mysql_query($sql)</strike>

```
$pdo->query($sql);
```

#### Количество строк в результате

> <strike>mysql_numrows($result)</strike>

```
$result->rowCount();
```

#### Получить следующую строку из базы

> <strike>$ar = mysql_fetch_array($result)</strike>

```
$ar = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

---

***PS:*** Настоятельно рекомендую также ознакомиться с механизмом подготовленных выражений (`prepared statements`). Они позволяют отделить данные от запроса, тем самым гарантируя защиту от SQL-инъекций и, иногда, переиспользовать подготовленные выражения для одинаковых запросов с разными данными